# Github actions checkout push/pull files only

Tags: github-actions

How can I get checkout push/pull files only through GitHub actions?

I have a github actions and use actions/checkout@v1 or actions/checkout@v2 but still all files are checked out... need only changes

Answer (score 0):

this is worked for me:

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0   # checkout all branch
- uses: jitterbit/get-changed-files@v1 # get changed files list
  id: files

- name: File name format check
  run: |
    for changed_file in ${{ steps.files.outputs.all }}; do
      echo "Changed files: ${changed_file}"          
    done
```